# Linear quantization in quantum electrodynamics?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, non-linear-systems, linear-systems

This is a continuation of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66067/2451) question.

What would be an example of linear quantization used on quantum electrodynamics? I ask this because QED is a nonlinear theory.

Comment: what does a linear theory mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_system#Definition

Comment: but... QED is an example of a quantum field theory, and  it is not given by a solution to a differential equation. so there is no concept of it being linear or not. or are you talking about the classical equation of motion and saying it is a bilinear operator? that's very unnatural. perhaps you're mixing up with the nature of the gauge group? QED is an abelian gauge theory, and QCD is a non-abelian gauge theory, for example. but that's very different from being linear or not.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this was prompted by one of my comments on [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66067/how-can-any-qm-interpretations-which-use-a-linear-schrodinger-equation-be-used-t).  The point I was making is that quantization, even of a system which is defined by a Lagrangian encapsulating a nonlinear set of equations of motion (such as in interacting QED) proceeds by defining a Hilbert space of states and operators on this space which evolve unitarily $$ |\Psi(t)\rangle = e^{-iHt}|\Psi(0)\rangle $$ As soon as you have this behaviour, you have a Schroedinger equation (just differentiate it to see).

So the linearity and presence of the Schroedinger equation is an integral part of the quantum picture.  That's all I was meaning in the comment in the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

Quantization is done for the free theory, without interactions, and this free theory is linear. For a scalar boson, for instance, each composant like $\phi(\vec k,t)$ is an harmonic oscillator (so the equation for $\phi(\vec k,t)$ is a linear equation), and you know how to quantize an harmonic oscillator.

When you  calculate the transition amplitudes, you are going to use the interaction term (S-Matrix), but the propagators you are using (in Feynmann diagrams) are calculated from the free theory quantization.

So there is no "quantization of interacting theory".